# How do you upgrade the version of Electron that used by project

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

I need to upgrade the version of electron that launches my app as the current version (4.0.0) has an old version of chromium (69.0.3497.106) which is causing a major problem. I have upgraded the version within the project by using `npm install electron@latest --save-dev`

But when the app is packaged or run with electron-forge start it reverts to the old 4.0.0 version.

console.log(process.versions)

```
  node: '10.11.0',
  v8: '6.9.427.24-electron.0',
  uv: '1.23.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  ares: '1.14.0',
  modules: '64',
  nghttp2: '1.33.0',
  napi: '3',
  openssl: '1.1.0',
  electron: '4.0.0',
  chrome: '69.0.3497.106',
  icu: '62.1',
  unicode: '11.0',
  cldr: '33.1',
  tz: '2018e'
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "appdmg": "^0.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "before-after-hook": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.2.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.2.1",
    "electron-positioner": "^4.1.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-updater": "^4.3.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.20.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.24",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "open": "^7.0.0",
    "parse": "^2.4.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.1.266",
    "pdfkit": "^0.10.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "screenres": "^2.0.1",
    "ssh2-sftp-client": "^4.2.0",
    "workingday-uk": "^1.1.2",
    "xero-node": "^3.0.0-alpha.6",
    "xml-formatter": "^1.2.0",
    "xml-parse-from-string": "^1.0.1",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.27",
    "xmlserializer": "^0.6.1",
    "xoauth2": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/maker-appx": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/maker-dmg": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-compile": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "@electron-forge/publisher-github": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "electron": "^16.0.7",
    "electron-notarize": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0"
  }
```